# find bash command returns ./ and how do I iterate through each file?

Tags: bash

I'm running bash script within Docker container.
All of my files are located in the workspace/app directory.

I cd into /app and use `find` commands to find directory path for each file.

The problem is when I use pylint, filename returns `./directory_name/file_name.py.`

How can I get ... `workspace/directory_name/file_name.py`?

```
#!/bin/bash

awd="$(pwd)app"
lint_path="${awd}/.pylintrc"
>>> cd /app
for file in $(find . -name '*.py' -type d); do
        filename=$(basename $file)
        if [[ $filename != "__init__.py" ]] ; then
                echo "$file"
                ^ prints "./directory__name/file_name.py
                How can I get "/app/directory_name/file_name.py"????
        fi
done
```

Comment: `for file in $(..anything...)` is literally item #1 in [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). If you want to read through a file or stream line-by-line *in general*, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). If you want to know how to use `find` properly, see [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).

Comment: Specify the name you want as the prefix instead of `.`, and make sure the current directory is such that the name will find the files.  For example, `find /workspace/app …` might do the job.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, eh, one can totally skip the `.` by using `-printf '%P\n'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Not in POSIX `find`.  Which `find` are you using?

Comment: @JohnBaek, btw, you can also just tell `find` itself to skip `__init__.py` files; there's no reason to implement that in shell.

Comment: ...waitaminute. `-name '*.py' -type d` is looking for *directories* with names ending in `.py`. How's that supposed to match `"./directory__name/file_name.py`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, GNU, of course.

Comment: I'm currently having to work on an AIX system; it's a brutal reminder about what's not in POSIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `find` an absolute path to `.` with `find "$PWD"`.

Also, use `while read` instead of `for`:

```
while read file; do
...
done < <(find "$PWD" -name '*.py' -type d)
```

Comment: `$(pwd)` is vastly inefficient compared to `$PWD` -- the former `fork()`s off a subprocess, runs the `pwd` command in it, and then has the parent process read from the FIFO with that subprocess's stdout... whereas `$PWD` just directly expands to the right value.

Comment: I'd also suggest `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do` and `-print0` in your `find`; that way even filenames with literal newlines, trailing whitespace, or backslashes work properly.

Comment: `file, do` is a syntax error, it should be `file; do`.